# PHP Update button without using Form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I would like to use a `<button>` to update my database.

I have seen a lot of example updating using `<form>` and `$_Post`.

Is there a way were could update the database by simply clicking the button and trigger an update function?

```
<div class='img'>
<div class='col-md-3'>
<div class='thumbnail'>
<img class='img-responsive' src='xxx'>
div class='caption' align='center'>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-Primary'>Update Image</button>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-Danger'>Delete Image</button>
</div></div></div>
```

Comment: Yes, by using javascript and ajax, or you could use an anchor tag that links to a page that executes your code and returns. Otherwise, you will have to use a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a form with a action attribute set to your PHP script and then look for one of the form variables like this

```
if(isset($_POST['formvariable'])) //Form has been submitted
```

This does however require page refresh.